# plotting a curvilinear line of best fit

Tags: r, plot, regression

What is the correct way to plot a curvilinear line of best fit on a graph? I am trying to provide a regression model as a parameter to the line- not specific points. In the model below the correct line should be a perfect fit (because there is no noise in the data). How do I plot the line of best fit from a linear model?

```
library(lattice)
vals<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=(1:10)^2)

xyplot(x~y,data=vals)
line(lm(x~y,data=vals)) #doesnt work
abline(vals$x,vals$y) #doesnt work
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need help with the plotting or the curvilinear line of best fit?

Comment: Plotting the line.... for some reason the syntax I tried doesn't work (I swear I read the docs before asking!)

Comment: Are you using `ggplot2` or another library?

Comment: I just realized that you're using `lattice` instead.

Comment: my apologies, I have added that as a library

Comment: I figured as much and incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a regression using the `lattice` library, you need to include a type parameter in the `xyplot` function. To get a linear regression use `"r"` and to get a non-linear regression (which is what you want here) use `"smooth"`. So this is what your code should look like

```
library(lattice)
vals<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=(1:10)^2)
xyplot(x~y,data=vals,type=c("p","smooth"))
```

The `"p"` is for the points and the `"smooth"` is for the smooth regression. This will result in a graph that looks like this

[image]

Alternative, if you, for some reason, did want a linear regression on this your code would look like this

```
library(lattice)
vals<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=(1:10)^2)
xyplot(x~y,data=vals,type=c("p","r"))
```

and your graph would look like this

[image]

Comment: If I use `smooth` as a parameter it doesnt fit the exact line of the linear model right? It fits the loess version. There is no way to specify a model directly? For example if I wanted to fit a ridiculous line to the points

Comment: Beyond the built in smooth and r, your best bet is to look to [here](http://lattice.r-forge.r-project.org/Vignettes/src/lattice-tricks/regression-lines.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you may be reversing the order of the arguments in the formula, since the conventional plot of y versus x would be returned from `xyplot( y ~ x )`. But if you really do want a linear regression with a second-degree polynomial fit, then use the `poly` function in the formula and the `predict` function to get the fitted values:

```
xyplot(x~y,data=vals)
plot(vals$y, predict( lm(x~poly(y, 2), data=vals)) )
```

It's not an exact fit since you are plotting the square root of x against x.

```
resid(  lm(x~poly(y, 2),data=vals)) 
#------------------------------
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
-0.57799840 -0.01438720  0.28444720  0.35772841  0.26036947  0.06297286 -0.14816950 
          8           9          10 
-0.27107622 -0.18807651  0.23418989
```

Another way (which does give an exact fit) is to use the `I` function inside the formula:

```
 plot(vals$y, fitted( lm(x~I(y^(1/2) ), data=vals)) )
 points(vals, pch="x", col='red')
 points(vals$y, vals$x, pch="x", col='red')
```

[image]